# Is there any way to annotate the TypeScript type of wasm-bindgen's JsValue to something more meaningful?

Tags: typescript, rust, wasm-bindgen

I have a Rust / Wasm function that I am generating TypeScript bindings for using wasm_bindgen. The output type for `JsValue` is `any`. Is there any way to manually annotate the type to something more meaningful without editing the auto-generated `*.d.ts`?

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
impl GameClient {
    pub fn game_list(&self) -> JsValue {
        JsValue::from_serde(&self.game_list).unwrap()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible atm. Coincidentally, it has been brought up recently: https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1591

Comment: @kuukuu Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Few solutions that I came across:

### ts-rs

[repo](https://github.com/Aleph-Alpha/ts-rs)

At the time of writing, this one has the most stars on github comparing to other solutions I found.

> "ts-rs" exposes a single trait, `TS`. Using a derive macro, you can implement this interface for your types. Then, you can use this trait to obtain the TypeScript bindings.

Example:

```rust
use ts_rs::TS;

#[derive(TS)]
#[ts(export)]
struct User {
    user_id: i32,
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
}
```

> When running cargo test, the TypeScript bindings will be exported to the file bindings/User.ts.

### Tsify

[repo](https://github.com/madonoharu/tsify)

> Tsify is a library for generating TypeScript definitions from Rust code. Using this with `wasm-bindgen` will automatically output the types to `.d.ts`.

According to their `README`, this library allows a code like this:

```rust
#[derive(Tsify, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[tsify(into_wasm_abi, from_wasm_abi)]
pub struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}
```

to become the following:

```js
export interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
```

Shortly after writing this answer i will test these library and comment regarding the one that worked for me. Hope this helps :)